# whats the approach to calculate GCD for 3 numbers

Tags: java, loops

What is the approach to find the GCD (Greatest Common Divider) with three numbers?
The following code shows the approach with 2 numbers, which uses an elementary version of Euclids algorithm (since input is positive) to calculated the GCD.

```
public class GCD {  
 public  static void main(String[] args) {

  int age1 = 10;
  int age2 = 15;

  int multiple1OfGCD = age1;
  int multiple2OfGCD = age2;



  while (multiple1OfGCD != multiple2OfGCD ) {

   if (multiple1OfGCD > multiple2OfGCD) {
    multiple1OfGCD -= multiple2OfGCD;
   }
   else {
    multiple2OfGCD -= multiple1OfGCD;
   }
  }

  System.out.println("The GCD of " + age1 + " and " + age2 + " is " + multiple1OfGCD);


  int noOfPortions1 = age1 / multiple1OfGCD;
  int noOfPortions2 = age2 / multiple1OfGCD;




  System.out.println("So the cake should be divided into "

     + (noOfPortions1 + noOfPortions2));

  System.out.println("The " + age1 + " year old gets " + noOfPortions1

     + " and the " + age2 + " year old gets " + noOfPortions2);

 } 
}
```

I want the output to look like in picture below:

[image: Want the output to look like this].

Comment: Why do people think this question shows research effort? Stack Overflow is not the right place to outsource your homework.

Comment: Guess what OP's following question was: [How do I calculate the GCD for 4 numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432503/compute-the-greatest-common-divisor-of-four-numbers) LOL Anyone want to guess what OP's next question will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope It will help

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
{
 int a,b,c;
 a=10;
 b=15;
 c=20;
 int d= gcd(a,b,c);
 System.out.println("The GCD of "+a+", "+b+" and "+c+ " is "+d);
 int cake=a/d+b/d+c/d;
 System.out.println("So the cake is divided into "+ cake);
 System.out.println("The "+a+ " Years old get "+a/d );
 System.out.println("The "+b+ " Years old get "+b/d );
 System.out.println("The "+c+ " Years old get "+c/d );
}

public static int gcd(int a, int b, int c){
 return calculateGcd(calculateGcd(a, b), c);
}

public static int calculateGcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0) return b;
    if (b == 0) return a;
    if (a > b) return calculateGcd(b, a % b);
    return calculateGcd(a, b % a);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track  I modified your code a little bit to make it slightly more easy to read:

```
class GCD {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int AGE1 = 10;
    final int AGE2 = 15;
    final int AGE3 = 20;
    getGCDAndCutCake(AGE1, AGE2, AGE3);
  }

  public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if(a == 0) return b;
    if(b == 0) return a;
    if(a > b) return gcd(b, a % b);
    return gcd(a, b % a);
  }

  public static void getGCDAndCutCake(int age1, int age2, int age3) {
    int gcdOf1and2 = gcd(age1, age2);
    int overallGCD = gcd(gcdOf1and2, age3);
    int pieces = (age1 + age2 + age3) / overallGCD;
    System.out.printf("The overall GCD of %d, %d and %d is %d\n", age1, age2, age3, overallGCD);
    System.out.printf("So the cake should be divided into %d\n", pieces);
    System.out.printf("The %d year old gets %d\n", age1, age1/overallGCD);
    System.out.printf("The %d year old gets %d\n", age2, age2/overallGCD);
    System.out.printf("The %d year old gets %d\n", age3, age3/overallGCD);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The overall GCD of 10, 15 and 20 is 5
So the cake should be divided into 9
The 10 year old gets 2
The 15 year old gets 3
The 20 year old gets 4
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Fujl/1)