# compute the greatest common divisor of four numbers

Tags: java

how can i compute the greatest common divisor of four  numbers, using a separate method in java to give output in picture below

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b, int c) {
    return calculateGcd(calculateGcd(a, b), c);
}
public static int calculateGcd(int a, int b) {
   if(a%b==0)
       return b;
   else {
       a=a%b;
       return calculateGcd(b, a);
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't so much a programming question as a math question. If you know how to calculate the GCD of two numbers, how do you calculate the GCD of N numbers? *GCD(a, b, c, d) = GCD(a, GCD(b, GCD(c, d)))*

Comment: Already 4 users down-voted this question. Be kind and explain what's wrong with this question.

Comment: @StephanVierkant Because it shows no effort?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Fair point, but down-voting without any comment show no effort too. By the way, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408788/whats-the-approach-to-calculate-gcd-for-3-numbers. Looks like he's outsourcing his homework.

Comment: @StephanVierkant I don't feel obligated to leave comments on every single post I downvote. Especially when that comment would basically just be parroting the downvote button tooltip. "This question shows no research effort..." My time is better spent elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  David Conrad said

> GCD(a, b, c, d) = GCD(a, GCD(b, GCD(c, d)))

You can use `java.math.BigInteger` class as below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int [] nums = {4,8,16,24};

    int gcd = nums[0];
    for (int i=1 ; i<nums.length; i++)
        {
             gcd = Getgcd(gcd,nums[i]);
        }

  System.out.println("The GCD of your n numbers is "+ gcd);

}

private static int Getgcd(int a, int b)

{
   return BigInteger.valueOf(a).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(b)).intValue(); 
}
```

**OR**

Build your own GCD method

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

  int [] nums = {4,8,16,24};

  int gcd = nums[0];
  for (int i=1 ; i<nums.length; i++)
    {
        gcd = Getgcd(gcd,nums[i]);
    }

System.out.println("The GCD of your n numbers is "+ gcd);    
}


public static int Getgcd(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0)
    { 
       return a;
    }

          return Getgcd(b, a%b); 
 }
```